# iOS UI Tests failing because "Application is not running, unable to get Accessibility data. Did you call -launch?"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8, xcode-ui-testing

I apologize if this is a duplicate question. I haven't been able to find one and am at a loss. My tests cannot pass because the app doesn't launch. I ran the tests and watched the simulator, and with the normal app (for the unit tests), it will open up and close after the tests have run but my "MyAppUITests" app, it looks like its ready to open and crashes on boot up which is why I'm getting the `Application is not running, unable to get Accessibility data. Did you call -launch` message.

**Console when UI Tests run**:

```
Test Case '-[FizzBuzzUITests.ViewControllerUITests 
    testTapNumberButtonIncrementsScore]' started.
    t =     0.00s     Start Test at 2017-04-10 10:44:25.544
    t =     0.00s     Set Up
    t =     0.01s     Tap "numberButton" Button
    t =     0.01s         Wait for app to idle
    t =     0.07s         Find the "numberButton" Button
    t =     0.08s             Wait for app to idle
    t =     1.13s             Find the "numberButton" Button (retry 1)
    t =     1.25s                 Wait for app to idle
    t =     2.29s             Find the "numberButton" Button (retry 2)
    t =     2.41s                 Wait for app to idle
    t =     2.48s             Assertion Failure: ViewControllerUITests.swift:25: Application is not running, unable to get Accessibility data. Did you call -launch?
```

**Simulator System Log when launching `MyAppUITests`**: (removed comp name and timestamp for readability)

```
assertiond[34190]: Submitted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.apple.test.MyAppUITests-Runner[0xc278][34190]
SpringBoard[34185]: [com.apple.test.MyAppUITests-Runner] Bootstrap complete with label: UIKitApplication:com.apple.test.MyAppUITests-Runner[0xc278][34190]
XCTRunner[34865]: assertion failed: 16E195 14E269: libxpc.dylib + 64131 [624BAF4F-2E03-34F8-ACBA-970B04637786]: 0x7d
XCTRunner[34865]: Running tests...
XCTRunner[34865]: No configuration specified in environment, checking for the most recent test configuration in TMPDIR (/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D/data/Containers/Data/Application/74576325-9D3A-411C-AC5B-1658CBD46272/tmp/)
XCTRunner[34865]: XCTRunner Arguments: (
    "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B2EA026D-FB60-4164-9C69-5EDDEC53427F/MyAppUITests-Runner.app/XCTRunner"
)
XCTRunner[34865]: XCTRunner Environment: {
    "CFFIXED_USER_HOME" = "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D/data/Containers/Data/Application/74576325-9D3A-411C-AC5B-1658CBD46272";
    CLASSIC = 1;
    "CUPS_SERVER" = "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.JL1cDBugQn/Listeners";
    "DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH" = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks";
    "DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH" = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib";
    "DYLD_ROOT_PATH" = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk";
    "DYLD_SHARED_REGION" = avoid;
    HOME = "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D/data/Containers/Data/Application/74576325-9D3A-411C-AC5B-1658CBD46272";
    "IOS_SIMULATOR_SYSLOG_SOCKET" = "/private/tmp/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D.launchd_sim/syslogsock";
    "IPHONE_SHARED_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY" = "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D/data";
    "IPHONE_SIMULATOR_CLASS" = D10;
    "IPHONE_SIMULATOR_ROOT" = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk";
    "IPHONE_TVOUT_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES" = "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D/data/Library/Application Support/Simulator/extended_display.plist";
    PATH = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/sbin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/sbin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/local/bin";
    "SIMULATOR_CAPABILITIES" = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPhone 7.simdevicetype/Contents/Resources/capabilities.plist";
    "SIMULATOR_DEVICE_NAME" = "iPhone 7";
    "SIMULATOR_EXTENDED_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES" = "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D/data/Library/Application Support/Simulator/extended_display.plist";
    "SIMULATOR_HID_SYSTEM_MANAGER" = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/Resources/Platforms/iphoneos/SimulatorHID.framework";
    "SIMULATOR_HOST_HOME" = "/Users/myuser";
    "SIMULATOR_LEGACY_ASSET_SUFFIX" = iphone;
    "SIMULATOR_LOG_ROOT" = "/Users/myuser/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D";
    "SIMULATOR_MAINSCREEN_HEIGHT" = 1334;
    "SIMULATOR_MAINSCREEN_PITCH" = "326.000000";
    "SIMULATOR_MAINSCREEN_SCALE" = "2.000000";
    "SIMULATOR_MAINSCREEN_WIDTH" = 750;
    "SIMULATOR_MEMORY_WARNINGS" = "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D/data/var/run/memory_warning_simulation";
    "SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER" = "iPhone9,1";
    "SIMULATOR_PLATFORM_RUNTIME_OVERLAY_ROOT" = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/RuntimeOverlay";
    "SIMULATOR_PRODUCT_CLASS" = D10;
    "SIMULATOR_ROOT" = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk";
    "SIMULATOR_RUNTIME_BUILD_VERSION" = 14E269;
    "SIMULATOR_RUNTIME_VERSION" = "10.3";
    "SIMULATOR_SHARED_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY" = "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D/data";
    "SIMULATOR_UDID" = "DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D";
    "SIMULATOR_VERSION_INFO" = "CoreSimulator 375.20 - Device: iPhone 7 - Runtime: iOS 10.3 (14E269) - DeviceType: iPhone 7";
    "TESTMANAGERD_SIM_SOCK" = "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.L8ty9mXSmp/com.apple.testmanagerd.unix-domain.socket";
    TMPDIR = "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D/data/Containers/Data/Application/74576325-9D3A-411C-AC5B-1658CBD46272/tmp";
    "XPC_FLAGS" = 0x0;
    "XPC_SERVICE_NAME" = "UIKitApplication:com.apple.test.MyAppUITests-Runner[0xc278][34190]";
    "XPC_SIMULATOR_LAUNCHD_NAME" = "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D.launchd_sim";
}
SpringBoard[34185]: [KeyboardArbiter] HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.DC33C1C6-5EBB-4156-9F1E-C1844955433D.launchd_sim[34164] (UIKitApplication:com.apple.test.MyAppUITests-Runner[0xc278][34190][34865]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
assertiond[34190]: Ignoring assertion request named "Deliver Message" from <BSProcessHandle: 0x7fd178711850; SpringBoard:34185; valid: YES> because process { pid 34865; bundleID (null) } is unknown.
assertiond[34190]: Deleted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.apple.test.MyAppUITests-Runner[0xc278][34190]
```

**UPDATE: Adding Test class code**

```
import XCTest

class ViewControllersUITests: XCTestCase {

    func testTapNumberButtonIncrementsScore() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        let numberButton = app.buttons["numberButton"]

        numberButton.tap()
        let newScore = numberButton.label
        XCTAssertEqual(newScore, "1")
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your test class code?

Comment: @joern just updated the question with the test class code!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ahhh, I feel stupid. Looking at another app, I was missing the following code in my test class:

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    continueAfterFailure = false
    XCUIApplication().launch()
}
```

Most importantly the `XCUIApplication().launch()` bit.